# Can I make a POST request within a custom function in the Excel JavaScript API?

Tags: office-js, add-in, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I'm building an Excel add-in using the Microsoft JavaScript API, and I'm having trouble making POST requests within a custom function. I am able to make a POST request just fine within a taskpane, but the same exact code is not working within a custom function.

Is there a way to make POST requests within custom functions? I know someone asked this question already here: [Unable to get POST request working in Excel custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396110/unable-to-get-post-request-working-in-excel-custom-functions). But I wasn't entirely sure what the answer meant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CORS not allowed: means you can't make the request. That said, the answer specifically states on which excel product you can't (Excel for Windows) and in which you can (Excel Online and Excel for Mac). Next time please comment on the answer you didn't understand and ask for clarifications there instead of opening a duplicate question. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get POST request working in Excel custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396110/unable-to-get-post-request-working-in-excel-custom-functions)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll comment on the original question next time :)

Comment: Now the Shared Runtime is in preview and it should meet your requirements. [Overview: Run your add-in code in a shared JavaScript runtime (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-shared-overview). Make sure the resource you access has CORS enabled.